# Input type="button" not overriding styles with class, but normal button is?

Tags: html, css, class

I have a button class that I'm using that overrides the gradients of my default `button` or `input type="button"` elements.  Here is the code for the defaults:

```
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"], button {
  background:#05ABE0;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #87E0FD 0%, #53CBF1 25%, #05ABE0 50%);
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #87E0FD 0%, #53CBF1 25%, #05ABE0 50%);
  background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #87E0FD 0%, #53CBF1 25%, #05ABE0 50%);
  background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #87E0FD 0%, #53CBF1 25%, #05ABE0 50%);
  background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #87E0FD), color-stop(25%, #53CBF1), color-stop(50%, #05ABE0));
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #87E0FD 0%, #53CBF1 25%, #05ABE0 50%);
  border:solid 2px #0076A3;
  border-radius:0.3em;
  -moz-border-radius:0.3em;
  -o-border-radius:0.3em;
  -webkit-border-radius:0.3em;
  font-size:1em;
  padding:0.4em;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-left:5px;  
  font-family:Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color:white;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 0px 2px 2px; 
  box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px white;
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px white;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px white;     
  background-size:100% 200%;
  -moz-background-size:100% 200%;
  -o-background-size:100% 200%;
  -webkit-background-size:100% 200%; 
  -moz-transition:all 0.1s linear;
  -o-transition:all 0.1s linear;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.1s linear;
}
```

Here is the override class:

```
.orange {
  border:2px solid #BF4619;
  background: #FF7700;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFD0A8 0%, #FFAE68 25%, #FF7700 50%);
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFD0A8 0%, #FFAE68 25%, #FF7700 50%);
  background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFD0A8 0%, #FFAE68 25%, #FF7700 50%);
  background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #FFD0A8 0%, #FFAE68 25%, #FF7700 50%);
  background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #FFD0A8), color-stop(25%, #FFAE68), color-stop(50%, #FF7700));
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFD0A8 0%, #FFAE68 25%, #FF7700 50%);
  background-size:100% 200%;
  -moz-background-size:100% 200%;
  -o-background-size:100% 200%;
  -webkit-background-size:100% 200%; 
}
```

When I use `<button type="button" class="orange">Orange button</button>` it works fine, but when I use `<input type="button" class="orange" value="Orange button" />` it reverts to the default styling that is **not** in the `orange` class.  Why is this?

PS: How do I do a multiline-indent on Stackoverflow? That's why my code is all in the same block in the example.

Comment: For multi-line indentation, I would suggest converting the tabs into spaces first. It makes switching between code/non-code blocks a bit easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Leniel Macaferi is right, but he doesn't explain why. The reason is specificity, which determines cascade order for rules with the same importance and origin; in both CSS2 and CSS3, `input[type="button"]` has specificity `11`, as it has one attribute selector and one type selector, while `.orange` has specificity `10`, as it has one class selector. In the case of the `button` selector, the specificity is `1` as `button` is an element type, thus `.orange` overrides it. (In the case where specificity is the same, later selectors in the document take priority.)

Fix: use `.orange.orange` instead of `.orange` to obtain a specificity of `20`, as repeated simple selectors are explicitly allowed in CSS3 (so it should work in most modern browsers, and any old ones that don't try to be smart and not increase specificity for repeated simple selectors).

Alternate fix: `[type="button"]` instead of `input[type="button"]` would instead reduce the specificity of the first rule, but could create problems if non-input elements in your HTML have `type="button"` set, as shown in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q9xKE/3/).

Usage of `!important` for each property would also solve your problem, but that's only really useful when the rule has one or two properties as you have to apply `!important` to each property.

More info:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#specificity
http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity

Comment: So what would be a fix for this? Should I specify the `orange` class to be a class of `input[type="button"]` by doing `input[type="button"].orange`?

Comment: @Witch-King I just modified my answer, but you should be able to double up the class (`.orange.orange` instead of just `.orange`) to increase the specificity.

Comment: Would you say that's good design though? Is it good practice to do that?

Comment: I'd say it's a hack. An interesting and probably useful hack, but a hack nonetheless.

Comment: So is there any other way around it?

Comment: @RyanKinal It's not a hack. It's an explicit part of the spec, at least for CSS3. I don't know if it's properly implemented in all browsers, of course, but it works in Firefox, at least. Here's a jsFiddle to test. http://jsfiddle.net/q9xKE/

Comment: What I'm saying is, would it be **bad** to use it?

Comment: I don't think it would be bad to use. It just feels like one of those edge-cases that is open to interpretation. I understand the class-stacking specificity gain, but it just seems wrong to apply the same selector to an element twice.

Comment: @Witch-King It shouldn't be, all the doubling-up of the class selector does is increase the specificity for the overall selector (in this case, going from (0,1,0) to (0,2,0)).

Comment: @RyanKinal It's no more open to interpretation than anything else explicitly stated in the spec (or, well, "recommendation"). "Note: Repeated occurrances of the same simple selector are allowed and do increase specificity." Doesn't mean all browsers will implement it right, of course, but it seems like it would make specificity calculation simpler as you don't have to keep track of what selectors came previously, just a running count of the different types of simple selectors that were encountered in the complex selector currently being parsed.

Comment: Alright.  I'll have to test it on other browsers.  At any rate, thanks for the help.

Comment: @JAB Huh... missed that bit, I guess. I was even looking for it. +1

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `input[type="button"]` in the first CSS rule.

Your second button is an `<input>` element and that matches that 1st CSS rule.

Comment: Sorry, you're saying that the `button` selector will also match `input[type="button"]`?

Comment: This selector `input[type="button"]` matches the `<input type="button" ...>` and hence the styles defined in that selector will take effect being mixed with what you have in the `.orange` class.

Comment: Yes, but the `button` element is also matched in that selector.

Answer (score -1):

Because and attribute selector (input[type="button"]) has a greater [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) than a classname.